# Debugging C/C++ Language Not Hitting Breakpoints

Tags: c++, c, macos, visual-studio-code

I have the following file `overflow.c` that I'm trying to debug through breakpoints **in Visual Studio Code macOS**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", n);
        n = n * 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've built it by typing `make overflow` in the terminal, which returns

```
cc   overflow.o   -o overflow
```

And I can do `./overflow` in the terminal to run it, which works. I have the **C/C++** extension by Microsoft installed. My `launch.json` looks like the following:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C Run",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/overflow",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I debug using the "C Run" configuration, it runs my entire code **without hitting any of my breakpoints** ([found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1kwk.png))

The "C Attach" is for attaching to an already-running app, which isn't applicable here. I've added the following to my PATH:

```
PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:${PATH}"
```

My debug console after debugging "C Run" config loads bunch of symbols, returns output from my print statements, and ends with

```
The program '/Users/ahlam/Downloads/workspace/overflow' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).
```

**EDIT**: I've also tried it with C++ and it has the same behavior. Made a `hello.cpp`, built using `g++ hello.cpp` and debugging just ran the entire code without hitting any breakpoints.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe start debug instead of run?

Comment: I went to the Debug menu, and clicked on the Green play button, hovering over it says, **Start Debugging**, so I think I'm debugging. Is there a different workflow you had in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to generate source-level debug information, which you can do by using the `-g` flag in `clang`:

```
clang -g overflow.c -o overflow
```

Do that instead of `make overflow`. You'll see a folder called `overflow.dSYM` in your directory. Debugging should now work.

Comment: thank you for this answer. I also want to state that the same thing is applicable to g++ when compiling in linux environments. if you use -g arg for g++ or clang, you'll get nice debugging in vscode.